# Microsoft Health API: Getting Flights Climbed

Tags: microsoft-band

Is there a way to get flights climbed from the API?  I am not seeing a way, but the web dashboard obviously has found a way.

Answer (score -1):

For Android: BandAltimeterEvent.getFlightsAscended()

And it should be similar for the other two platforms as well.

Though this sensor is only available for Microsoft Band 2

Comment: Actually Im looking for the same concept from the Cloud API.